# C# CodeDom Cant type in "

Tags: c#, codedom

I want to compile a code with codedom which should connect to my ftp server.
But I cant type in the credentials because of the ""...

Look here :

```
Temp.AppendLine(@"request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid","userpassword");");
```

If I type " in the code, it automatic ends the content of the brackets...
Help?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to escape the content by using double quotes, like this:

```
Temp.AppendLine(@"request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(""userid"",""userpassword"");");
```

Comment: Alright worked thank you! Maybe you know about CodeDom, I have also another question. How can I use the text of an TextBox in the code which I want to compile? I want to take the credentials from the textboxes of my form (the builder) :)

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately my knowledge on CodeDom is limited; The answer to this question was actually depended only on C# string syntax. I suggest you open another question mentioning specifically that - how to capture the input from a CodeDom textbox.

Comment: @GumGun If you have another question, *ask a new question*, don't use comments for that.

Answer (score 1):

`Temp.AppendLine(@"request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(""userid"",""userpassword"");");`

Escape the `"` with `""`